# awk - using printf to format only one field of output?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, printf

A very basic query, but one which I haven't been able to resolve. I am a **very** basic *awk* user.

I wish to take a file (no more than 100 records) into *awk*, and output the file modified only by adding a line number (0 padded) at the start of each line.

Thus, input file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et

dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam
...
```

Output file:

```
001 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
002 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
003
004 dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam
...
```

My little one liner to do the line numbering goes (rather obviously)

```
awk '{print NR, $0}' *infile*
```

From which I get

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
2 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
3
4 dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam
...
```

Note that the input file has blank records which need to be preserved (but would be  better output unnumbered)

I also know that I can do

```
awk '{printf "%03i", NR}' infile
```

to give me

```
001
002
003
...
```

What I can't see is how to combine the two.

I'm using awk/gawk 4.0.1 on Linux, so the the rest of the usual Linux toolbox is available to me if there are alternate ways of doing what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `printf` to print the number and then the content:

```
awk '{printf "%03i %s\n", NR, $0}' *infile*
```

`03i` will print the line number - `NR` and `%s` will print the current line - `$0`. The rest is formatting - need to add space between the both and `\n` for a line break between every line.

Comment: perfect. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`nl` from the GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#nl-invocation) to number your lines:

```
nl -w 3 -n rz -s ' ' infile
```

- `-w` (`--number-width`) says how many columns to reserve for the line number
- `-n` (`--number-format`) says how to format the number; `rz` is "right justified, leading zeros"
- `-s` (`--number-separator`) is the string to insert between the number and the line itself; in this case, a space

This defaults to skipping empty lines:

```
$ nl -w 3 -n rz -s ' ' infile
001 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
002 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et

003 dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam
```